# Is Gravitational Red shift equal to $mgh$

Tags: classical-mechanics, semiclassical

Is gravitational shift - $\frac{gh}{c^2}$  (according to pound-rebka experiment) always equal to $PE=mgh$? because assume the gravitational pull, $g$, is equal to $1$ then we can say $g = 1$ similarly let us assume the height the photon wants to travel is also $1$ therefore $h=1$ and now let us assume the mass is $1$ so $m = 1kg$ now that we know if we plug in this into the following equations we get an imbalance as:

$$\frac{gh}{c^2} = \frac{1}{c^2} = 1.11265006 * 10^{-17} J\approx Negligible$$ 
Now lets assume we convert this energy into mass again using $E=mc^2$ where $m = E/c^2$ which is $1kg$ with some 
while if we now plug in the values into the potential energy we get: $$PE = mgh = 1*1*1 = 1J$$
and we know $1 > (1.11265006 * 10^{-17})$
and since we know that potential energy is always equal to kinetic energy we can say that Gravitational Redshift creates an energy imbalance which goes against laws of Thermodynamics so what makes sure that gravitational redshift becomes equal to $mgh$?

Comment: It's approximately the case in the limit where the distance from the center of the mass distribution is much larger than the Schwarzchild radius for that mass, see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/126614/44126) to a closed question.

Answer (score 5):

## Always include units

**Always.** No exception. Ever. If your Nobel prize winning professor writes down equations like this without units, you look him in the eye and tell him he's not doing physics.

Your analysis suffers from the fatal flaw that you are comparing quantities with different units. $gh/c^2$ is dimensionless. It is the fractional energy change in a photon over a short distance where $g$ can be taken to be constant.

On the other hand, $mgh$ is the absolute change in potential energy over a similarly short distance. It has units of energy.

Moreover, $mgh$ doesn't apply to massless particles like photons anyway. Classical physics doesn't deal with relativistic things very well, since otherwise we would have predicted gravitational redshift centuries before general relativity.

You might see some things work out better if you scale to the same dimensions. If $mgh$ is the absolute change in energy, then the fractional change in energy should be $mgh/E$. If you just blindly apply $E = mc^2$, you retrieve $gh/c^2$. Be warned, though, that such carefree application of a cliche equation like this isn't always a good idea. If you ever find yourself talking about the mass of a massless particle, you should immediately start backtracking and looking for any suspect steps you took, rather than just forging ahead by throwing more equations at the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Chris White, it helped. That in mind so is my current "equation" wrong? Also do we have to always ensure that energy is conserved even if it seems as if it isn't?

Comment: Dear Rohan, I am afraid that it's not even wrong. Why do you think that "potential energy is always equal to the kinetic energy"? If they were equal, we wouldn't have to phrases for them, would we? If America were always the same as Russia, we would probably eliminate one of the words, too. It's also bizarre what you may mean by "gravitational red shift is equal to $mgh$". $mgh$ is a potential energy in joules, so how it can be equal to a gravitational red shift which is arguably dimensionless (a frequency ratio)? Your statements make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: At the end, you probably want to see that the gravitational red shift is compatible with the energy conservation law. Of course that it is. The gravitational red shift may really be derived from that. If a photon is sent upwards in the gravitational field, it will redden by the redshift factor, and therefore lose energy. The loss is exactly equal to the loss of the total relativistic energy of an object that you would throw up but it would slow down due to gravity.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought differently I thought wrong in fact my concept of understanding was wrong. Thanks @LubošMotl for clarifying my doubts.

Comment: @LubošMotl "America" and "the US" and "USA" and "the States", "Ireland" and "Erin", "the Moon" and "Luna" and "La Lune". Furthermore, if what you say is true, then why are there many languages each with different words for equal concepts. Not arguing with the basic point, but the way you made that point has some holes

Comment: Jim, your question is off-topic. I wasn't talking about different languages. I was just saying that the potential energy and the kinetic energy are obviously different quantities that are almost never equal to each other, and that this conclusion is common sense because the adjectives make it very clear that we want to distinguish two different and in some sense even "opposite" things.